# EditText lines are overlapping other views

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I got 3 `TextView` and 3 `EditText` in my Layout.

The problem i have is that when I type more into my EditText will overlap my other views..

How my layout looks
[image]

How it looks after i put my text

[image]

I want if possible, while the `EditText` is getting bigger, the views under to go down, and I can scroll to see them, or any other method to make the layout look normal..

My XML code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Words(Separated by space)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
        android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Time (In seconds)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Words(Separated by space)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time (In seconds)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Add" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: This makes one of my textview disapear and the views won't be centered.. look here http://postimg.org/image/t19jn72wt/

Comment: make gravity center..it s coming fine for me..which device you are using and are you using same code as mine???

Comment: Yea, I just did copy paste to my layout.. i'm using HTC Desire

Comment: Use android:gravity="center" and android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: My bad, I thought i have installed it already, but there was NO Storage error, and it was the old install, it works , thanks!

Comment: i didnot get you.what u had installed??now your problem got resolved or not??

Answer (score 1):

remove relative layout and add orientation attribute of linear layout to VERTICAL

Comment: This makes one of my textview disapear and the views won't be centered.. look here http://postimg.org/image/t19jn72wt/

Comment: Use android:gravity="center" and android:layout_width="fill_parent"